# iOS Chrome - How to calculate window height minus height of address bar

Tags: javascript, html, ios, google-chrome, ipad

I am developing browser games that have only one full-size canvas element in body.
When run these games in iOS9.2(iPad) Chrome(Ver 47.0.2526.107), the bottom area of game screen is not shown. (It didn't happen several months ago. Even now this neither happen in Safari, nor Android 5.0.2 Chrome 47.0.2526.83)

These game programs first calculate size of window (the area showing html document when  address bar is shown), and places a canvas element having the size.
Since some version of Chrome, the "size of window" is interpreted as the size of window when address bar is NOT shown.

I tried to get the height of window by:

- screen.availHeight
- window.innerHeight
- $(window).height()
- document.documentElement.clientHeight
- document.height
- $(document).height()

but they all returns the same value, the height when address bar is NOT shown.

Test code is shown in http://jsrun.it/hoge1e4/4Ygq   I want to know the value of the scale at bottom of the screen when address bar is shown.
(see picture)
[image]

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be solved by version-up.

I checked it on ver.49.0.2623.73